# how to prove $(A^2)^+=M^2$ if $M=A^+$ and A is a symmetric matrix?

Tags: matrix-equations, symmetric-matrices, pseudoinverse

Here $A^+$ is Moore–Penrose inverse.
My question is:
If $M=A^+$ and A is a symmetric matrix,then how to prove $(A^2)^+=M^2$?

Comment: Real symmetric, I guess. Just prove that $(A^+)^2$ has the four defining properties of a Moore-Penrose inverse of $A^2$

Comment: @martini if it's not real symmetric, is the conclusion correct?